# Export grid to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, grid, pdf-generation

i am using obout grid, and i am trying to export grid to PDF, the export is working perfect when i fill the grid using sqldatasource but when i fill the grid using a stored procedure and function in code behind i am getting this error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

the problem is in the inner loop

```
//How add the data from the Grid to pdf table
        for (int i = 0; i < Grid1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Hashtable dataItem = Grid1.Rows[i].ToHashtable();

            foreach (Column col in Grid1.Columns)
            {

                    PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dataItem[col.DataField].ToString(), font8)));
                    PdfPCell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR; //change the text direction for the arabic
                    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);

            }
        }
```

when i trace the error i notice that when it reach to the last column it will continue to read another column which is not there {Column}, that's why i am getting error in this line

```
 PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dataItem[col.DataField].ToString(), font8)));
```

which empty

the full code

```
 private void ExportGridToPDF()
{       
    // Stream which will be used to render the data
    MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream();

    Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    try
    {            
        //Create Document class object and set its size to letter and give space left, right, Top, Bottom Margin
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fileStream);

        doc.Open();//Open Document to write

        //Font font8 = FontFactory.GetFont("TAHOMA", 7);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\\\windows\\\\fonts\\\\tahoma.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        iTextSharp.text.Font font8 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

        //Write some content
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("ASP.NET Grid - Export to PDF");

        //Craete instance of the pdf table and set the number of column in that table
        PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(Grid1.Columns.Count);
        PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;

        //Add headers of the pdf table
        foreach (Column col in Grid1.Columns)
        {                
            PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(col.HeaderText, font8)));
            PdfPCell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR; //change the text direction for the arabic               
            PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
        }

        //How add the data from the Grid to pdf table
        for (int i = 0; i < Grid1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Hashtable dataItem = Grid1.Rows[i].ToHashtable();

            foreach (Column col in Grid1.Columns)
            {

                    PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dataItem[col.DataField].ToString(), font8)));
                    PdfPCell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR; //change the text direction for the arabic
                    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);

            }
        }

        PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 15f;

        doc.Add(paragraph);
        doc.Add(PdfTable);
    }
    catch (DocumentException docEx)
    {
        //handle pdf document exception if any
        MessageBox.Show(docEx.ToString());
    }
    catch (IOException ioEx)
    {
        // handle IO exception
        MessageBox.Show(ioEx.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ahndle other exception if occurs
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close document and writer
        doc.Close();
    }

    // Send the data and the appropriate headers to the browser
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=oboutGrid.pdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileStream.ToArray());
    Response.End(); 
}
```

any suggestion

Comment: I don't have VS loaded right now so I can't do too much but you're creating one collection (`dataItem`), then iterating over another collection (`Grid1.Columns`) but referencing the first again (`dataItem[col.DataField]`) which is just asking for trouble. Can't you just `foreach` over the `dataItem`?

Comment: as i mention before that i have 8 columns and Grid1.Columns read 9 column how can i make it read only 8 to avoid the error

Comment: You did not mention those numbers. We do not know your database nor your sproc. Since we don't have access to you database please compare the actual contents of `Grid1.Columns` and `dataItem` and provide them here. My comment above said to not bother iterating over `Grid1.Columns` in the first place, did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manage to solve the problem after seeking help from another forum
by changing the code that reading grid header

```
PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(Grid1.Columns.Count-1);
```

and also

```
//Add headers of the pdf table
    foreach (Column col in Grid1.Columns-1)
    {
```